# How to send UDP packets to clients who are on the same LAN

Tags: networking, udp, lan

I'm currently working on the UDP networking of a game.

Let's say there are two players on the same NAT/LAN. They consequently share the same external IP. They both join the same game server which is at another location and has a different external IP.

How can the game server send UDP packets to a specific player over the LAN?

Everything is fine when every player is on a different LAN, but when two or more are on the same LAN I know don't how to reach them.

BTW I'm using C# but I guess it doesn't really matters here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your description I assume their access to the server is through a NATting device. In this case you don't have anything to do, the two clients will be seen coming from the same IP address but different source port, hence easily distinguishable.

Comment: Oh, but how do I know the port that each client is using?

Comment: Does the UDP port has to be forwarded on the client-side gateway?

Comment: Any idea what happens if both game clients randomly pick the same source port? Will the router usually NAT the source port?

Comment: Yes the router will, nothing would work elsewhere. DNS name resolutions for a start is UDP based so that's a pretty well tested feature.

Comment: @asmo I don't understand your question. But basically it just works as long as you base your server code on the you really receive (that will have been transformed by the NATting router) and don't try to guess what the original port and address were. Do not embed such information in the protocol itself, it's a recipe for a nightmare. For the client itself the server being on the LAN or beyond makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly: even if the server only needs to send packets, it should still listen for a first packet that will be used to determine the client's IP and port. Am I correct?

Comment: Yeah obviously, then it's not a server if it's not the client initiating the communication.

Comment: Actually, I asked this because I was initiating the communication with TCP. Therefore the server was already aware of the client and directly sent data through UDP, without waiting for an UDP packet coming from the client.I thought it would be better to do the handshake with TCP, since it's more reliable than UDP.

Comment: Well you need to do an UDP handshake as one could NAT TCP traffic differently than UDP traffic wrt addresses too anyway, you weren't actually sure of the address, it just happened to work in your case, as for the port you have no mean at all to guess so there is no escaping the UDP handshake, the reliability part of TCP is just based on resending non acknowledged packets, something simple enough to do on your own.